# Incrementar a ProgressBar com um Timer causa um Bug Visual! A progress só carrega até metade mas o valor fica CHEIO! c#

Tags: c#, formulário, windows

Oi, Estou criando um projeto mais ou menos assim:
Clicko e aparece uma ProressBar, eu a incremento com um Timer, eu contei e qd uma variavel incrementada de 1 em 1 chega a 11, temos +/- 3 segundos, é oq eu quero! Em seguida a progressbar precisa ser "resetada" e desaparecer. O processo se repente sempre que eu "clicko".
MAS, Qd eu faço isso com a progressbar e o timer, da um bug visual: a progressbar nao carrega até o maximo, ela carrega cerca de 60%, 40%, e diz que o valor ja esta cheio(11)!
Preciso de ajuda, é pra um projeto da escola!

Obs.: Este código e o print não são do projeto, somente é um exemplo que fiz pra exemplificar o problema.

Codigo(Nao encaixou muito bem, vejam tudo, por favor):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //progressBar1.Increment(1);
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
            if (progressBar1.Value == 11) // 11 é o valor Maximo da ProgressBar
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("oi");
                progressBar1.Enabled = false;
                progressBar1.Visible = true;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Por vezes é necessário forçar a actualização visual dos componentes. Use `progressBar1.Refresh()` ou `progressBar1.Invalidate()` após `progressBar1.Value += 1;`

Comment: Nao funcionou nao ;--; usei os 2 ou só um dos 2, em varias partes mas de jeito nenhum funcionou :(

Comment: Pra quanto tempo está configurado o timer?

Comment: o padrao mesmo, 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme essa resposta do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469876/progressbar-lag-when-setting-position-with-pbm-setpos).
Este é um problema conhecido do `Windows`.

O `C#` utiliza o componente `ProgressBar` nativo do Window. 
A partir do Windows 7, animações mais "suaves" foram feitas nos componentes, fazendo com que ocorra um pequeno atraso em suas animações.

Porém há um pequeno detalhe, quando você diminui o valor do `ProgressBar` não há esse atraso.
Isso porque não foi implementado esse animação suave ao diminuir o valor da `ProgressBar`.

Logo podemos nos aproveitar dessa situação para forçar a atualização rápida do `ProgressBar`.
O truque é aumentar o valor e diminuir e aumentar novamente.

Exemplo:

```
progressBar1.Value += 1;
progressBar1.Value -= 1;
progressBar1.Value += 1;
```

E quando chegar no máximo, fazer assim:

```
progressBar1.Maximum += 1;
progressBar1.Value += 1;
progressBar1.Value -= 1;
progressBar1.Maximum -= 1;
```

Eu mesmo havia encontrado essa solução em outros lugares já, mas não tinha entendido o porque dela funcionar. Até procurei como funcionava o componente `ProgressBar`, mas basicamente o `c#` só interage através de mensagens com ele.

Não é a melhor solução de todas, até parece uma "gambiarra", porém funciona...

Comment: Funcionou! ainda buga um pouco mais só quando chega no final, tipo, nao carrega o ultimo, mas de qualquer forma ja vale muito! Serio, mt obg xD

Comment: Show de bola, é meio bugado mesmo. Se te ajudou e funcionou pode marcar esta resposta como correta.